# Adobe XI Pro set save path using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------Do not edit the XML tags--------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------

//<Document-Actions>
//<ACRO_source>Document Will Save</ACRO_source>
//<ACRO_script>
/*********** belongs to: Document-Actions:Document Will Save ***********/
this.saveAs("/y/Misc/" + this.documentFileName);

//</ACRO_script>
//</Document-Actions>
```

What I am trying to do is find out how to put the save path embedded in each adobe file I am using so that it can be automatically saved in certain directory without any path being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that assuming you have Adobe XI the javascript is not needed.

1. Go to Tools
2. Go to Action Wizard
3. Go to Create New Action
4. Select Save & Export (on the left)
5. Select Save
6. Select the middle button (Green Circle with a plus in it and an arrow)
7. Select Save on the left
8. Select Save to Local Folder (Find Folder you want to save to)
9. Select Save in the lower right hand corner. (Name and Add a description to your new action)

To run the action

1. List item
2. Go to Tools
3. Go to Action Wizard
4. Select action under Actions
5. Click Start (and it runs)